# Is there a way to get the column names by order from a JSON file in SparkSQL ?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a JSON file and the keys would be my column while loading into Spark SQL. Now when i want to retrieve the column names, it was retrieved in Alphabetical order. But i want the details should be in the order of how its present in the file

my input data 
is

```
{"id":1,"name":"Judith","email":"jknight0@google.co.uk","city":"Évry","country":"France","ip":"199.63.123.157"}
```

Below is my way to retrieve the column names and build a single string

```
val dataframe = sqlContext.read.json("/virtual/home/587635/users.json")
    val columns = dataframe.columns 
    var query = columns.apply(0)+" STRING"  
    for (a <- 1 to (columns.length-1))
    {
      query = query + ","+ columns.apply(a) + " STRING" 
    }
    println(query)
```

This gives me the output like below

```
city STRING,country STRING,email STRING,id STRING,ip STRING,name STRING
```

But i want my output as

```
id STRING,name STRING,email STRING,city STRING,country STRING,ip STRING
```

Comment: Is the field order known at compile time, as assumed by the answer below from @Radian, or does it need to be determined dynamically based on what is in the file?

Comment: i want the fields to be determined dynamically

Comment: Is your data such that each line is a separate JSON document?

Comment: yes.. The data i showed you is the first line of my file.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `select` with the columns correctly ordered

```
val dataframe = 
  sqlContext
    .read
    .json("/tmp/test.jsn")
    .select("id", "name", "email", "city", "country", "ip")
```

If you tried this at the shell, you will notice the correct order

> dataframe: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: bigint, name: string,
>   email: string, city: string, country: string, ip: string]

By executing the rest of your script, the output is as expected

> id STRING,name STRING,email STRING,city STRING,country STRING,ip
>   STRING

Comment: Radian, my case is that the fields should be determined only at run time.

Comment: So what is the usecase you are trying to solve here? Usually you will need to know the schema before writing the code. At somepoint you will have to use the fieldnames to do operations on your data.

If the usecase is limited to the example on your question. Why not just read the first line from the file and print the schema without using Spark.

Comment: I'm trying to create a Cassandra table out of a JSON dataset using SparkSql. I want my code should be more generic so that i don't need to change my code every time whenever my scheme changes.

Comment: I guess you'd better use `createCassandraTable` from spark-cassandra-connector.

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md#creating-a-new-cassandra-table-from-a-dataframe-schema

This won't guarantee the columns order as well, but is the simplest solution I can think of.